# If width is larger than the screen size, height is changed too on iOS/Android (Constraint Issue)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, mobile

I have an element inside body and it's **larger than the screen size**.
I limited the **height** of body, so I thought only the width of body would be changed.
However, on **mobile devices**, **if you change width larger than the screen width, the height would be changed too**..

I'd like to **maintain the original body height(100%)**.
Is there a way to maintain the height?

↓The height is weird as you can see..
[Chrome Dev Tool picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCsu4.png)

This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0">
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    body, html {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    #el {
        width:2100px;
        color:red;
        border:2px solid red;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="el">aaaa</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = window.innerWidth + '<br>' + window.innerHeight
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this post on my own.

All I had to was simply set the following meta tag.
**height=device-height** seems to be the key if you need to do things like this! Hope this post helps people [like me](https://github.com/exis9/)... (^o^)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```